# Using output from bash script as variable within Terraform

Tags: bash, docker, terraform

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction, I am looking at verbalising our Kubernetes version within our Terraform module as currently its hard coded.

Every now and then we get an error saying that our "orchestration version" isn't valid when we deploy our cluster - this is due to Azure dropping our Kubernetes version... (We deploy our dev/uat envs daily)

So I came up with the idea of using a variable for our version so we can always deploy avoiding the "invalid orchestration" error. I scripted the bash script for what I need;

```
az aks get-versions --location westeurope --query 'orchestrators' -o tsv | awk '{print $3}' | tail -2 | head -n 1
```

But now I wish to use the output from ^^^ to use as our Kubernetes version within our Terraform module we deploy daily.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've had a look at using build-args within the docker container.

Comment: You mean you want command substitution, ie. `variable=$( command | command | head -n1 )` ?

Answer (score 11):

Use `external` datasource:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external

The only trouble is that the output and (optional) input must be valid Jsons with some [limitiations](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12249).

Example:

```
data "external" "myjson" {
  program = [
    "${path.module}/scriptWhichReturnsJson.sh",
  ]
  result {

  }
}

...
resource ...  {
  value = data.external.myjson.property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to store the output of the bash-script into a file, and use the Local provider to read that file:

```
data "local_file" "foo" {
    filename = "${path.module}/foo.bar"
}
```

and then you can use the file content via `${local_file.foo.content}`.

But I would check what data sources are available in the azure provider. You could use the [azurem_kubernetes_cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/kubernetes_cluster.html) data resource to get the kubernetes_version of the currently deployed cluster:

```
data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "test" {
  name                = "myakscluster"
  resource_group_name = "my-example-resource-group"
}
```

Which makes the kubernetes version via the `kubernetes_version` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass the bash script output to a terraform module through Terraform CLI

1. Assign the output of bash script into a variable, say, `kubernetes_version=$([your-bash-command])`
2. In the same bash file, pass this variable through the terraform CLI. It looks something like this:

```
terraform [action] -var "tf_kubernetes_version=$kubernetes_version" [some-other-options] [tf-root-directory]
```

The `action` can be `plan/destroy/apply`. Visit [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html) for further details.

3. Make sure that the tf-root-directory contains variable declaration

```
variable "tf_kubernetes_version" {}
```

4. Pass the variable tf_kubernetes_version from root to module

```
module "kubernetes_module" {
   source = "[tf-module-directory]"
   md_kubernetes = "${var.tf_kubernetes_version}"
}
```

5. Make sure that the tf-module-directory contains variable declaration

```
variable "md_kubernetes_version" {}
```

Finally, you can use ${var.md_kubernetes_version} within your terraform module.

Note: You may opt to add default value for the terraform variable declaration in Steps 3 & 5 for a baseline kubernetes version.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hashicorp's External](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external) to do this, but your program can only read JSON `stdin` (or doesn't read anything at all), and must give the output as JSON.

Here's my example using [External 2.3.1](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/2.3.1/docs/data-sources/external) (latest version as per October 2023):

data.tf:

```
data "external" "gcloud_auth_token" {
  program = [
    "sh", "${path.module}/gcloud-token.sh",
  ]
  query = {
    # You can pass something to STDIN of your program here, 
    # but as per current version, the input will be given as JSON (map of string)
  }
}
```

gcloud-token.sh:

```bash
# AUTH_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)

AUTH_TOKEN="YourTokenGoesHere"
OUTPUT=$(jq --null-input --arg token "$AUTH_TOKEN" '{"token": $token}')

echo "$OUTPUT"

# This will give output: 
# {
#   "token": "YourTokenGoesHere"
# }
```

output.tf:

```
output "token" {
    value = data.external.gcloud_auth_token.result.token
}
```

Then run:

```
chmod a+x gcloud-token.sh
terraform init
terraform apply
```

You will see this output after running `terraform apply`:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

token = YourTokenGoesHere
```

Note:
You may need to install `jq` on your Mac / Linux / Windows WSL to run this example yourself.

Just run this:
`brew install jq` (mac)
or
`sudo apt-get install jq` (Linux, WSL. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546590/7069108))

Answer (score -1):

You can use Command Substitution to assign the result of a command to a variable. I took the liberty of cleaning up your text processing into a single `awk` statement. The following Bash should assign the second to last value of the third column of your `az` output to the variable `kubernetes_version`.

```
kubernetes_version=$(
  az aks get-versions -o tsv \
    --location westeurope --query orchestrators \
      |awk '{penult=ult; ult=$3} END{printf penult}'
)
```

This is untested as I don't use Azure; please comment any questions/concerns.